# Postgres compare timestamp with long unix timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a timestamp attribute in a table on which I want to place a condition in a sql query where the condition value is a unix timestamp (i.e. numeric long value).

```
[...] table.timestampattr > 6456454654 [...]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `extract(epoch from ...)` to get a Unix timestamp from any of the PostgreSQL time and date types (see [Date/Time functions in manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html)).

So your query fragment could be written:

```
[...] extract(epoch from table.timestampattr) > 6456454654 [...]
```

Alternatively, the `to_timestamp` function performs the opposite conversion, so you could also write:

```
[...] table.timestampattr > to_timestamp(6456454654) [...]
```

Comment: Here to_timestamp() is the better choice. It evaluates to a constant. Extracting epoch from the timestamp column has to be evaluated for every row.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' Good point. The key being that `to_timestamp` is defined as `IMMUTABLE`, so the query planner should know to run it once and cache the result.

Comment: Both functions are immutable. The difference is that, in *this* case, to_timestamp() is called with a constant argument, and extract() is called with a different argument on each row. If the OP had stored the Unix epoch in the table, and needed to compare it to a constant value of type timestamp, then extract() would be the better choice.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' Right you are! I guess what I was fumbling towards was a hint to those not familiar that it is the `immutable` attribute of the function that makes this possible, not some internal magic. A user-defined function (for instance, for converting an MS "ticks" value) would get the same performance benefit if it was defined as `immutable`, but would be evaluated for every row if it was not.

Comment: to_timestamp() seems to be what I was looking for but for some reason the conversion from long is not correct. 

For instance to_timestamp(1360417525156) returns "45079-11-30 23:59:16-05" instead of "Sat, 09 Feb 2013 13:45:25 GMT"

Comment: @JackGibson The Unix timestamp for "Sat, 09 Feb 2013 13:45:25 UTC" is 1360417525; it looks like you've got millisecond precision rather than seconds. `to_timestamp` accepts a float, so you can add a decimal point and get the value you were after: `select to_timestamp(1360417525.156)`.

Comment: @IMSoP Thanks! I actually built the SQL statement in Java and just had to divide the timestamp long by 1000!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a constant and set it to the current data and then `select` it like below:

```
    WITH myconstants (current_unix_date) as (
       values (extract(epoch from now() at time zone 'utc')) 
    )

    SELECT * From table, myconstants
    WHERE table.target_date_time_unix > myconstants.current_unix_date
```